# Is it possible extract and merge a single json object from multiple json files?

Tags: php, json

Sorry for the confusing title. I am having a bit of an issue here merging some JSON files. I need to merge all the products into one array in a separate file.

I have a directory full of same structured json files. I am using glob to select all files and decode->append-->encode json files into one large file.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$files = glob("*.json");
$newDataArray = [];
foreach($files as $file){
    $thisData = file_get_contents($file);
    $thisDataArray = json_decode($thisData);
    $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray;
}
$newDataJSON = json_encode($newDataArray);
file_put_contents("merged.json",$newDataJSON);
?>
```

Now, the above code seems to work great but I only want to extract all the products.

Quick example of what I need to achieve.

**File1.json**

```
{
  "status": true,
  "user": {
    "username": "sally",
    "avatar": "/images/default-avatar.png",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "35vR4hr",
        "title": "Picture 1",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 2,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 1,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
      {
        "id": "na1Id4t",
        "title": "Picture 2",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 0.75,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 3,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**File2.json**

```
    {
  "status": true,
  "user": {
    "username": "Jessica",
    "avatar": "/images/default-avatar.png",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "wjiefi94",
        "title": "Picture 3",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 2,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 1,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
      {
        "id": "n34idwi",
        "title": "Picture 4",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 0.75,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 3,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want the data to be merged like:

**merged.json**

```
{
    "products": [
      {
        "id": "wjiefi94",
        "title": "Picture 1",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 2,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 1,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
      {
        "id": "n34idwi",
        "title": "Picture 2",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 0.75,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 3,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
            {
        "id": "n34idwi",
        "title": "Picture 3",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 0.75,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 3,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
            {
        "id": "n34idwi",
        "title": "Picture 4",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 0.75,
        "currency": "CAD",
        "stock_warning": 3,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      }
    ]
  }
```

I hope this makes sense. I feel like I have hit a dead end here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) { $newDataArray[] = $thisDataArray; } else { echo $file ." does not contain valid JSON"; }`. Put that inside your foreach loop.

Comment: Good to know I can ignore errors. But now it's only just saving the first json it reads to merged.json. I think I made an error somewhere in the loop.

Comment: Just edited that comment. Made a small mistake. Also, you shouldn't ignore errors. That code is to inform you about files that have a problem. Not to just ignore them.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I updated my post with the actual json I am using to test instead of an example. Your edited code just sends an error now for some reason. I wasn't clear enough with my JSON that I am trying to merge. I am attempting to merge just the products but when merging the jsons it does this anyway automatically. I do agree ignoring errors is bad practice, I guess that's not what I meant by ignore. Thanks

Comment: Ye my bad again.. Having your old code in there as well is confusing. This is how your code should look like: [https://pastebin.com/m0Wf0VD5](https://pastebin.com/m0Wf0VD5) - It should run just fine and output any files that have an issue for you.

Comment: No problem, yea it is only saving the first json file it reads to merged.json still. I think I have a loop error, i'll have to try a few things. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well getting a bit too late for me. This is as far as I got: [https://pastebin.com/LC0NKX3g](https://pastebin.com/LC0NKX3g) It kind of gives you the result you want, but it's far from perfect yet. Still you might have a use for it

Comment: This is perfect, I cant thank you enough. I didn't know array_merge was a thing. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible for you to call an external tool like "jq"? handling json (just like csv), especially with many files, is not something you should be doing manually.

btw, your example does not have commas between products 2 and 3 and 3 and 4.

Your new code on line 5 should probably read like this with the array brackets? Otherwise you are overwriting the contents of the last files:

```
$thisDataArray[] = json_decode($thisData);
```

And why are you merging products from Sally and Jessica into the same user? Maybe you can just extract all the products objects into one file?

More of a code review than an answer, hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alfred. I think this is actually a great idea, I am going to look into how to achieve this. Probably much easier. Also, you were correct, I made an error in the merged result. Thanks for the heads up. And as far as the code: $thisDataArray[] = json_decode($thisData); I am not sure, I had tried this before but was trying to simplify it. I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, that was also a mistake merging the two names together. I fixed my json, again, to show what I am trying to achieve.